# Getting incorrect intersection point in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The purpose is to draw all three angle bisectors of a triangle. Here ABC is a triangle. The pairs (a1,a2), (b1,b2) and (c1,c2) represents start point and end point of arc at vertex A, B and C respectively. What I am trying to do is I am taking the lines A -- ($(a1)!0.5!(a2)$) and corresponding side BC and getting their intersecting point (say k1). Then I will draw the angle bisector using vertex and intersection point k1. And repeating it for remaining two vertexes.
But my problem is that when I am trying to get intersection point of the lines I am getting the point c1.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in,marginparsep=0pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% vertices of the triangle
\coordinate[label=below:{$A(x_1,y_1)$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{$B(x_2,y_2)$}] (B) at (4.5cm, 0);
\coordinate[label=above:{$C(x_3,y_3)$}] (C) at (6cm, 5cm);

% drawing triangle
\draw[name path=trg] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

% circle at each vertex A, B and C to get intersection
% points with triangle
\path[name path=circa] (A) circle (6mm);
\path[name path=circb] (B) circle (6mm);
\path[name path=circc] (C) circle (6mm);

% labeling intersections of circles and each vertex angle
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circa, by={a1,a2}}]; % at vertex A
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circb, by={b1,b2}}]; % at vertex B
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circc, by={c1,c2}}]; % at vertex C


% drawing arc at each vertex
\draw[bend right] (a1) to (a2);
\draw[bend right] (b2) to (b1);
\draw[bend right] (c2) to (c1);

\path[name path=AB] (A) -- (B);
\path[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
\path[name path=CA] (C) -- (A);

% determining intersection of angle bisector and 
% corresponding side of the triangles
\path[name path=abs1] (A) -- ($(a1)!0.5!(a2)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs1 and BC, by={k1}}];
\fill[red] (k1) circle [radius=2pt];

\path[name path=abs2] (B) -- ($(b1)!0.5!(b2)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs2 and CA, by={k2}}];
\fill[red] (k2) circle [radius=2pt];

\path[name path=abs3] (C) -- ($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs3 and AB, by={k3}}];
\fill[red] (k3) circle [radius=2pt];

% drawing angle bisectors
% the problem is that k1, k2, and k3 are at the same place
\draw [red] (A) -- (k1); 
\draw [red] (B) -- (k2);
\draw [red] (C) -- (k3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The segment `abs1` and the segment `BC` have no intersection...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The segment `abs1` and the segment `BC` have no intersection... You can enlarge your `abs1` segment by:

```
\path[overlay,name path=abs1] (A) -- ($(A)!20!($(a1)!0.5!(a2)$)$);
```

I arbitrarily choose the value `20` and add the `overlay` option so as not to interfere with the calculation of the bounding box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% vertices of the triangle
\coordinate[label=below:{$A(x_1,y_1)$}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:{$B(x_2,y_2)$}] (B) at (4.5cm, 0);
\coordinate[label=above:{$C(x_3,y_3)$}] (C) at (6cm, 5cm);

% drawing triangle
\draw[name path=trg] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

% circle at each vertex A, B and C to get intersection
% points with triangle
\path[name path=circa] (A) circle (6mm);
\path[name path=circb] (B) circle (6mm);
\path[name path=circc] (C) circle (6mm);

% labeling intersections of circles and each vertex angle
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circa, by={a1,a2}}]; % at vertex A
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circb, by={b1,b2}}]; % at vertex B
\path [name intersections={of=trg and circc, by={c1,c2}}]; % at vertex C


% drawing arc at each vertex
\draw[bend right] (a1) to (a2);
\draw[bend right] (b2) to (b1);
\draw[bend right] (c2) to (c1);

\path[name path=AB] (A) -- (B);
\path[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
\path[name path=CA] (C) -- (A);

% determining intersection of angle bisector and 
% corresponding side of the triangles
\path[overlay,name path=abs1] (A) -- ($(A)!20!($(a1)!0.5!(a2)$)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs1 and BC, by={k1}}];
\fill[red] (k1) circle [radius=2pt];

\path[overlay,name path=abs2] (B) -- ($(B)!20!($(b1)!0.5!(b2)$)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs2 and CA, by={k2}}];
\fill[red] (k2) circle [radius=2pt];

\path[overlay,name path=abs3] (C) -- ($(C)!15!($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)$);
\path[name intersections={of=abs3 and AB, by={k3}}];
\fill[red] (k3) circle [radius=2pt];

% drawing angle bisectors
% the problem is that k1, k2, and k3 are at the same place
\draw [red] (A) -- (k1); 
\draw [red] (B) -- (k2);
\draw [red] (C) -- (k3);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```